# Generic запрос к статической константе

Tags: java, generics

Есть 4 класса

```
 public abstract class Fruit {
        protected String name="Fruit";
        protected static final float WEIGHT=0f;
    }

    public class Orange extends Fruit {
        private String name="Orange";
        public static final float WEIGHT=1.5f;
    }

    public class Apple extends Fruit {
        String name="Apple";
        public static final float WEIGHT=1.0f;
    }  

        public class  Box<T extends Fruit> {
            private List<T> content = new ArrayList<>();
            public void put(T fruit){
                content.add(fruit);
            }
            Box(){
                if(T instanceof Apple)
            }
            public void put(List<T> fruits){
                content.addAll(fruits);

            }
            public double getWeight(){
                if(content.size()==0) return 0;
                return content.size()*T.WEIGHT;
            }}
```

Почему T.WEIGHT всегда отрабатывает как Fruit.WEIGHT.

```
Box<Apple> boxApple = new Box<>();
boxApple.put(new Apple());
System.out.println(boxApple.getWeight());
```

Результат выполнения 0.
Разве не должно для этой box T.WEIGHT==Apple.WEIGHT

Comment: Нельзя так делать. для статических полей и методов в дженерике нельзя вызвать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дженерики в Java это отчасти можно сказать "синтаксический сахар". Т.е. при компиляции Ваш код  "превратит" все места T в Fruit. Код T.WEIGHT превратится в Fruit.WEIGHT

Answer (score 2):

```
public class  Box<T extends Fruit> {
            private List<T> content = new ArrayList<>();
```

в content лежат объекты `Fruit` они ничего не знают о других классах. Поэтому константа всегда берётся из класса `Fruit` и там она равно нулю.

Сделайте во `Fruit` метод

```
abstract float getWeight();
или
float getWeight(){};
```

abstract заставит наследников переопределять метод

в наследниках его переопределите (возвращайте константный вес) и при подсчете веса вызывайте его. Тогда будет вызван метод класса наследника `Fruit` и будет получена точный вес.

---

Подумайте вот ещё о чем, что если в одном из классов наследника не будет константы WEIGHT?

В байт коде класса нет дженериков. Компилятор за вас расставляет нужные классы. Дженерики обеспечивают типизацию во время написания, чтобы ошибка выскакивала на этапе компиляции а не во время работы.

Поэтому по факту ваш класс выглядит так

```
public class  Box<Fruit> {
            private List<Fruit> content = new ArrayList<>();
```

поэтому и вызывается константа Fruit.WEIGHT